# Is it a good practice to add names to __all__ using a decorator?

Tags: python, coding-style

Is this a good practice in Python (from [Active State Recipes -- Public Decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576993-public-decorator-adds-an-item-to-__all__/))?

```
import sys

def public(f):
  """Use a decorator to avoid retyping function/class names.

  * Based on an idea by Duncan Booth:
  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/11cbb03e09611b8a
  * Improved via a suggestion by Dave Angel:
  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/3d400fb22d8a42e1
  """
  all = sys.modules[f.__module__].__dict__.setdefault('__all__', [])
  if f.__name__ not in all:  # Prevent duplicates if run from an IDE.
      all.append(f.__name__)
  return f

public(public)  # Emulate decorating ourself
```

The general idea would be to define a decorator that takes a function or class
and adds its name to the `__all__` of the current module.

Comment: Fixed the title, as some people pointed out

Comment: While this seems like a nice idea, I find that it confuses my IDE (PyCharm 2016.1.4), which mostly defeats the purpose. Given adequate IDE support, I would use it.

Comment: Getting this decorator 100% bullet-proof appears to be harder: see the [Python bug #26632](https://bugs.python.org/issue26632) and the [`atpublic` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atpublic) mentioned there.

Comment: Cross reference: I've [cited your decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895257/1468366) (with one name change) in a CW answer to the question of how to write such a decorator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's a good practice.   This decorator allows you to state your intentions right at function or class definition, rather than directly afterwards.  That makes your code more readable.

```
@public 
def foo():
    pass 

@public 
class bar():
    pass

class helper(): # not part of the modules public interface! 
    pass
```

**Note:**  `helper` is still accessible to a user of the module by `modulename.helper`.  It's just not imported with `from modulename import *`.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it's a good practice outright.  The advantage of having an `__all__` explicitly defined at the beginning of a module is that anyone (possibly you) looking at it can very easily determine what is exported via `import *` and what is part of the public API of the module.  Using a public decorator makes this much more difficult.  However, if you use a decorator, you can tell while looking at a member of the module whether it is in `__all__` or not.  So both have their respective pros and cons.

Comment: Everything darkfeline said plus - it breaks intellisense/code-completion on IDEs with naive code tokenizers.

Answer (score 17):

The more idiomatic way to do this in Python is to mark the private functions as private by starting their name with an underscore:

```
def public(x):
      ...


def _private_helper(y):
    ...
```

More people will be familiar with this style (which is also supported by the language: `_private_helper` will not be exported even if you do not use `__all__`) than with your `public` decorator.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the problem the decorator solves: keeping the names in `__all__` up to date.

Comment: @EdL That's because if you consistently use underscores for "private" things and no underscores for public things, you won't need `__all__` at all

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Won't any imported modules be exported?  You probably still want to block those.

Comment: @NeilG  you can `import module as _module`

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Good idea, but that is definitely not common practice

Comment: @NeilG Neither is the `@public` decorator proposed, _common_ practice is using `__all__` as intended

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Sure, but `@public` is a world better than prepending an underscore to every usage of every module.

Comment: @NeilG You can also clean up your imports via an explicit `del module`, but whether _that_ is truly better I dare to doubt...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler You can't just `del module` at the end, your exported functions that use `module` won't work!

Comment: @TobiasKienzler @NeilG [Parts of the standard library](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/collections/__init__.py) use the pattern `import module as _module`, so I'd call it a fairly established practice.

Comment: @flornquake Good point about `del module`. And about `import as _`. Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't automatically add names to `__all__`, it simply allows you to add a function to all by decorating it with `@public`. Seems like a nice idea to me.

Comment: By automatically, I basically meant w/o typing the name in the list explicitly

Comment: Yes. (11 more characters to go)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a bit subjective, but I like the idea. I usually use `__all__` in my modules but I sometimes forget to add a new function that I intended to be part of the public interface of the module. Since I usually import modules by name and not by wildcards, I don't notice the error until someone else in my team (who uses the wildcard syntax to import the entire public interface of a module) starts to complain.

Note: the title of the question is misleading as others have already noticed among the answers.