# Export __all__ as something that is not itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want `my_module` to export `__all__` as empty list, i.e.

```
from my_module import *
assert '__all__' in dir() and __all__ == []
```

I can export `__all__` like this (in 'my_module.py'):

```
__all__ = ['__all__']
```

However it predictably binds `__all__` to itself , so that

```
from my_module import *
assert '__all__' in dir() and __all__ == ['__all__']
```

How can I export `__all__` as an empty list? Failing that, how can I hook into import process to put `__all__` into importing module's `__dict__` on every top level `import my_module` statement, circumventing module caching.

Comment: **Why in heavens name** would you want to do that? `__all__` is metadata about `my_module`, not about the module into which you are importing this.

Comment: Really, this sounds like a terrible idea. What's wrong with putting `__all__ = ()` into your modules instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I want to impelment a decorator for explicitly exporting entities like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206089/is-it-a-good-practice-to-add-names-to-all-using-a-decorator). The guy there sets `__all__` on first decorator application, so not explicitly exporting anything causes it to implicitly export everything. I am trying to improve on this design: if the decorator is imported, then export nothing by default, regardless of it's usage.

Comment: You cannot do what you want, not with hacking `__all__` in any case. I'd go as far as saying that such side effects are quite un-pythonic; *explicit is better than implicit* here. If you want to make everything private, the module *author* should set `__all__ = []` explicitly.

Comment: This is all quite apart from other objections that apply here: using `from module import *` goes against the PEP 8 style guide and use of the decorator in that post makes using static code analysers (such as auto-completion tools) at best a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with saying this is, in my mind, a *terrible idea*. You really should not implicitly alter what is exported from a module, this goes counter to the [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *Explicit is better than implicit.*.

I also agree with the [highest-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6206624) on the question you cite; Python already has a mechanism to mark functions 'private', by convention we use a leading underscore to indicate a function should not be considered part of the module API. This approach works with existing tools, vs. the decorator dynamically setting `__all__` which certainly breaks static code analysers.

That out of the way, here is a shotgun pointing at your foot. Use it with care.

---

What you want here is a way to detect *when* names are imported. You cannot normally do this; there are no hooks for `import` statements. Once a module has been imported from source, a `module` object is added to `sys.modules` and re-used for subsequent imports, but that object is not notified of imports.

What you *can* do is hook into attribute access. Not with the default module object, but you can stuff any object into `sys.modules` and it'll be treated as a module. You could just subclass the module type even, then add a `__getattribute__` method to that. It'll be called when importing any name with `from module import name`, for *all* names listed in `__all__` when using `from module import *`, and in Python 3, `__spec__` is accessed for *all* import forms, even when doing just `import module`.

You can then use this to hack your way into the calling frame globals, via [`sys._getframe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```
import sys
import types

class AttributeAccessHookModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '__all__':
            # assume we are being imported with from module import *
            g = sys._getframe(1).f_globals
            if '__all__' not in g:
                g['__all__'] = []
        return super(AttributeAccessHook, self).__getattribute__(name)

# replace *this* module with our hacked-up version
# this part goes at the *end* of your module.
replacement = sys.module[__name__] = AttributeAccessHook(__name__, __doc__)
for name, obj in globals().items():
    setattr(replacement, name, obj)
```

Comment: imo, using `sys._getframe` makes it more like pointing a rocket launcher at your foot…

Answer (score 0):

> The guy there sets `__all__` on first decorator application, so not explicitly exporting anything causes it to implicitly export everything. I am trying to improve on this design: if the decorator is imported, then export nothing my default, regardless of it's usage.

Just set `__all__` to an empty list at the start of your module, e.g.:

```
# this is my_module.py
from utilitymodule import public

__all__ = []

# and now you could use your @public decorator to optionally add module to it
```

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious, this is exactly what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: @yurikilochek Well, know that it’s not possibly nor recommended to automatically have `__all__` preinitialized empty. The whole *point* of `__all__` is so that you can *configure* the current module in a clear way. If you were to obfuscate this and move it into a cryptic process, you would absolutely harm its use case. And btw. you shouldn’t be relying on all-imports anyway.