# Auto compute __all__ to only use explicitly defined import

Tags: python

I have an `__init__` file in a folder `foo/` which import some modules

```
from a import ClassA
from b import *

__all__ = [s for s in dir() if not s.startswith('_')]
```

My folder `foo/` contains additional `.py` files

```
foo/
  a.py  # Contain ClassA
  b.py  # Contain ClassB
  c.py
```

`a` import `c`, so when I import `a`, it automatically import `c` and add it to the `locals()` scope of the `__init__`, even if `c` isn't imported in `__init__`.

I would like the `__all__` of my init file to only contains the imports that I explicitly declared in the files (so just `ClassA` and `ClassB`). However, `c`, even if not imported in the `__init__` is automatically added.

How can I dynamically compute `__all__` to only contains the imports that I explicitly define in my `__init__.py`. Both `locals()` or `dir()` also return other files from the module `foo`.

Ideally, the solution should be both Py2.7 Py3 compatible.

Comment: Could not reproduce this - with this file structure and imports, `dir()` should not include `c`. Either way, `__all__` is not mandatory, and in this case omitting it will yield the result you want.

Comment: At least classes and functions carry a `__module__` attribute which identifies the module of their definition. You may need to filter which items really come from the desired modules.

Comment: @roeen30 I've run more test, so it seems that because `a` import `c`, `c` gets automatically added to `dir()` even if I haven't explicitly imported it. I updated the question. 
Also in this case I really need the `__all__` as it is used by an external program I don't control.

Comment: To check for directly vs. indirectly imported modules you may have to parse the file.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `foo.c` will show up in `foo`s `locals()` once it is imported, that's how python imports work. `__all__` is there to allow you to control what `from foo import *` does, by explicitly listing what should be imported.

So if you want `from foo import *` to import `a` and `b`, your `__init__.py` only needs to contain:

```
__all__ = ['a', 'b']
```

You don't need to import the submodules before that at all, only if you want to add code to your `__init__.py` that uses them.

So if you want to avoid the redundancy of having to import and add the submodules to `__all__`, just drop the imports and use `__all__` explicitly.

Comment: I know I can manually set `__all__`, but the question is about dynamically computing `__all__`.
In practice, my imports are not just `import a` but `from a import MyClass`, `from b import *`, so just using `__all__` won't work.
I updated the question

Comment: After importing stuff at package level there's not really any way to decide wheather a submodule was imported directly or indiretctly by some other submodule. Like @MichaelButscher said above, you'd have to parse the file to do so. Or try something like the decorator suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895077/export-decorator-that-manages-all) to mark what you want exported. Which seems a lot of work to support star imports which are regarded as [bad parctice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) by many...